# Unprocessable Entity to Upload a File in Angular to FastAPI

Tags: fastapi, angular17

I have this error when i send the file from Angular to FastAPI, this is the python code.
I use the same name ("fileInput"), when i do the requirement from Postman it works correctly.

```
@app.post("/resultado")
async def basic_form(fileInput: UploadFile= File(...)):

    resultado= Module.Consulta(fileInput.file)
    resultado2= Module2.Consulta2(resultado)
    
    df= pd.read_excel(resultado2, index_col= "id")
    df1 = df.head(5)
    print(df1)
    if not df1.empty:
        return {"message": "OK"}
    else:
        return {"message": "WRONG"}
```

Angular Code

```
  onFileSelected(event: Event): void {
    const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    const files: FileList | null = target.files;
    if (files && files.length > 0) {
      this.fileToUpload = files[0];
    }
  }

  onSubmit(): void {
    if (!this.fileToUpload) {
      console.error('No file selected');
      return;
    }

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('fileInput', this.fileToUpload); 

    formData.forEach((value, key) => {
      console.log(key, value);
  });
    this.http.post('http://localhost:8000/resultado', formData).subscribe(
      (response) => {
        console.log('File uploaded successfully:', response);
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error('Error uploading file:', error);
      }
    );
  }
}
```

I try to send a POST from Angular to FastAPI and recive and ok msg

Comment: The body of the 422 error will contain information about whether something is missing or something fails validation.